# Error: EACCES, permission denied in command #yo angular

Tags: javascript, node.js, yeoman, yeoman-generator, yeoman-generator-angular

I come yeoman and angular begun to use that command but I threw this error, which I can do?

> `#yo angular`

```
/usr/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/update-notifier/node_modules/configstore/node_modules/graceful-fs/polyfills.js:8
    cwd = origCwd.call(process)
                  ^
Error: EACCES, permission denied
    at process.cwd (/usr/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/update-notifier/node_modules/configstore/node_modules/graceful-fs/polyfills.js:8:19)
    at process.cwd (/usr/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/insight/node_modules/configstore/node_modules/graceful-fs/polyfills.js:8:19)
    at process.cwd (/usr/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/download/node_modules/decompress/node_modules/decompress-tar/node_modules/tar/node_modules/fstream/node_modules/graceful-fs/polyfills.js:8:19)
    at process.cwd (/usr/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/download/node_modules/decompress/node_modules/decompress-tarbz2/node_modules/tar/node_modules/fstream/node_modules/graceful-fs/polyfills.js:8:19)
    at process.cwd (/usr/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/download/node_modules/decompress/node_modules/decompress-targz/node_modules/tar/node_modules/fstream/node_modules/graceful-fs/polyfills.js:8:19)
    at process.cwd (/usr/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/download/node_modules/decompress/node_modules/decompress-unzip/node_modules/temp-write/node_modules/graceful-fs/polyfills.js:8:19)
    at process.cwd (/usr/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/glob/node_modules/graceful-fs/polyfills.js:8:19)
    at new Environment (/usr/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/env/index.js:45:42)
    at createEnv (/usr/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/yeoman-generator/index.js:38:10)
    at init (/usr/lib/node_modules/yo/cli.js:71:40)
```

Comment: Maybe using `sudo` command can fix your problem

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Prefix your command with `sudo` will fix your problem but it is just a quick workaround.
Another workaround would be to set the permission of this directory to your user. For instance

```
sudo chown $YOUR_USER -R /usr/lib/node_modules
```

**But the best way would be to follow the great advice on the following [gist](https://gist.github.com/isaacs/579814)**

Answer (score 0):

Use following command

> sudo chown -R $Your_User:$Your_Group /usr/lib/node_modules